# C - Linux Kernel: Closing two kthreads freezes machine

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, freeze

**EDIT:** I *think* I solved the problem. I will add my own answer/solution as soon as I am at work again tomorrow.

---

I am working on a kernel module for the Linux kernel 3.16.x. My module is supposed to receive and send ethernet frames, so I created two threads. One for the receive part, one for the transmit part. It is working fine.

My issue appears when I try to close the device file of the module and unload it. To be precise, it happens when trying to kill my threads. The machine (I am testing on a virtual machine, with Ubuntu 14.04) freezes before there is any output whatsoever. However, when I remove the "thread killing part" from the code, it does not freeze anymore. That is why I am quite certain, the issue stems from the way I handle the killing of the kthreads.

Here are my two threads:

TX THREAD: The semaphore tx_sem is up'ed in another part of the code.

```
static int tx_task(void *par)
{
    device->tx_task_running = 1;

    allow_signal(SIGTERM);
    while (!signal_pending(current) && device->tx_task_running) {
        /* wait until there is something to send */
        down_interruptible(&device->tx_sem);

        if (signal_pending(current)) {
            PRINTD("device_TX_task(): Received kill signal\n");
            break;
        }

        /* check if device is still initialized before continuing*/
        if (!device->init_flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
    device->tx_task_running = 0;
    return DEVICE_RET_OK;
}
```

RX THREAD

```
static int device_rx_task(void *par)
{
    device->rx_task_running = 1;

    /* task loop */
    allow_signal(SIGTERM);
    while (!signal_pending(current) && device->rx_task_running) {
        rxlen = kernel_recvmsg(device->sock, &msg, 
            (struct kvec *)&iov, 1, DEVICE_PAY_SIZE, 0);

        if (signal_pending(current)) {
            PRINTD("device_rx_task(): Received kill signal\n");
            break;
        }

        if(rxlen < 0) {
            PRINTD("device_RX_task(): Got error when receiving\n");
            break;
        }

        /* check if device is still initialized before continuing*/
        if (!device->init_flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
    device->rx_task_running = 0;
    return DEVICE_RET_OK;
}
```

These guys run until I try to close my device. When closing the kernel module, this function gets called and this is when it crashes. For example, if I comment the "send_sig" functions out, it does not crash. It also crashes when I try to manually kill the threads:

```
int Device_DevTerm(int dev)
{
    device->init_flag = 0;

    send_sig(SIGTERM, device->rx_thread, 0);
    send_sig(SIGTERM, device->tx_thread, 0);
    device->rx_task_running = 0;
    device->tx_task_running = 0;

    return DEVICE_RET_OK;
}
```

I googled and searched for a long time in order to find the problem, but so far I was not successful. Since I already spent a LOT of time for this issue, I decided to ask you guys.

What am I doing wrong here?

p.s. I don't think I ever posted here, I just read a lot. I hope my question is clear and concise enough. Probably not.

Comment: If it is crashing post the stack trace.  If you meant hang, use SysRq to find the hung task.

Comment: Unfortunately I seem to be unable to do so. 
When I look into /var/log/syslog/ there is nothing about the hang. I guess it froze before any output occurred.
When I try SysRq (which I did not know before) nothing happens, it stays frozen.

Maybe the fact that it is a virtual machine does not help, I am not sure. I will continue to try to gather any helpful information, but up to now I am not able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems like I found my problem.

When setting up the msghdr for the kernel_recvmsg() function, I used to do it like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in client;

MEM_SET(&client, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

/* setup receive parameter */
msg.msg_name = &client;
msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
msg.msg_control = NULL;
msg.msg_controllen = 0;
msg.msg_iov = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
```

Now I changed the routine to:

```
struct sockaddr_in client[3];

MEM_SET(&client[0], 0x00, 3 *sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

/* setup receive parameter */
msg.msg_name = &client[1];
msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
msg.msg_control = NULL;
msg.msg_controllen = 0;
msg.msg_iov = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
```

With this it does not crash anymore. Then I found the following comment in our code base:

```
/*
 * NOTE:
 * use three times the size of struct sockaddr_in as workaround
 * for a possible kernel bug which has been seen on a Ubuntu 64bit
 * system
 * after the call of kernel_recvmsg 2 bytes behind the structure
 * client had been corrupted on the stack
 */
```

I am not sure how true that is and whether or not this encompasses my whole problem, but it seems to fix it.